# Min Heap implementation using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapsort

Below is the code which i have written to perform Heap sort on the integer List items.
However the end result is not coming as desired, as it needs to sort the List in Minimum order.

Also,can someone help in explaining the Complexity of this particular code.

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap=[]

    def insert(self,num):
        self.heap.append(num)

    def printHeap(self):
        print(self.heap)


    def heapify(self, index):

        size=len(self.heap)-1

        left=2*index+1   #calculating Left Node
        right=2*index+2  #Calculating Right Node
        minE=index

        """ Calculating the Minimum element Value from the List """
        if left <= size and self.heap[left] < self.heap[index]:
            minE=left

        if right <= size and self.heap[right] < self.heap[minE]:
            minE=right

        if minE != index:  # Swapping elelments only when MinE is not equal to the Parent Node
            self.swap(minE, index)
            self.heapify(minE)

    """ Method to Swap the elements of the Heap List  """

    def swap(self,first, second):
        self.heap[first],self.heap[second] = self.heap[second], self.heap[first]


    def minHeap(self): # Main calling Method to perform Heap

        loc=len(self.heap)-1 

        i=0
        while i <= loc:  #Running the Loop till the last element
            self.heapify(i)
            i+=1

heapList=Heap()

heapList.insert(10)
heapList.insert(15)

heapList.insert(5)
heapList.insert(2)
heapList.insert(18)
heapList.insert(3)

print(" Original List")
heapList.printHeap()

print(" Performing Heap sort:")
heapList.minHeap()

print("Final Result: ")
heapList.printHeap()
```

Result which i am getting from above code is:

```
Original List
[10, 15, 5, 2, 18, 3]
 Performing Heap sort:
****Final Result:
[5, 2, 3, 15, 18, 10]
```

However the expected would be:

```
[2,5,3,15,18,10]
```

Would appreciate your valuable comments.
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the idea that that's a heapsort? Your `minHeap` method is performing a heapify operation, not a heapsort (and your `heapify` is performing a sift-down, not a heapify).

Comment: ...actually, your loop is backward, so `minHeap` isn't performing any sort of sensible operation at all.

Comment: So, how should we perform the Heapify operation in correct way.. ? Do we need recursion to be more accurate. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I guess i am able to do the heapify flow, with the below change in code:

    def minHeap(self):
        length=len(self.heap)


        for i in reversed(range(length//2)) :
            self.heapify(i)